# Пунктуация и пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация

Достаточно последней части цитаты... Мужа она везёт — «в Ростов, где медицинский персонал надёжен и многочислен и где каждая минута жизни больного будет проходить на глазах родни и его и её». Из речи Ф. Плевако 1890 г.

Современная пунктуация нисколько не изменила бы фразы из XIX в.?

Comment: *Мужа она везёт* — Ваши слова, не относятся к фразе?

Comment: "Если бы жена тяготилась мужем, если бы смерть была желанной мечтой ее, то к чему было ей тревожиться о состоянии его здоровья и везти его в Ростов, где медицинский персонал надежен и многочислен и где каждая минута жизни больного будет проходить на глазах родни и его и ее?"

Comment: Вопрос исключительно о знаках препинания. Цитата взята в кавычки. «Мужа она везёт» заменяет обширную предшествующую часть предложения.

Answer (score 2):

В кавычках знаки поставлены правильно Возможно, некоторые сомнения вызывает отсутствие запятой между И ЕГО И ЕЁ, но я думаю, что тут всё нормально: ***"Между двумя однородными членами, связанными дважды повторенным союзом и, запятая не ставится, если однородные члены образуют тесное смысловое единство, например: Мать усмехнулась, и радость и печаль задрожали на ее губах. (Стельм.)"*** [Однородные члены, связанные повторяющимися и парными союзами](http://dictations.ru/odnorodnye-chleny-svyazannye-povtoryayushhimisya-i-parnymi-soyuzami/)

Comment: Не надо эту группу рассматривать как уточнение?

Comment: Думаю, не надо (родни чьей? его и её), Но если при чтении паузу сделать значительную и интонацию использовать, как при уточнении, - тогда можно поставить тире, например. Я читаю без паузы.

Comment: Если бы ЕГО И ЕЁ только, но ведь — И ЕГО И ЕЁ. Разница не малая. Без паузы И превращается в простой союз. Относительно контекста эта деталь (чья родня, сколько родни) важна для защиты подсудимой. Спасибо.